# Push Notifications Android using Parse and back4app | issue wtih GCM Sender ID

Tags: android, firebase, parse-platform, back4app

I am using back4app push notification feature (which uses Firebase) to send notifications to my app
I am using api 28 and the documentation [here](https://www.back4app.com/docs/android/push-notifications/parse-server-push-notifications) suggest using GCM Sender ID which is now not used anymore in Firebase according to this [link](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/04/time-to-upgrade-from-gcm-to-fcm.html)

How can I connect to back4app in this case?

Comment: you can copy the sender id in the firebase project setting -> cloud messaging

Comment: I figured out the problem my parse set up wasn't correct